# Convert py file to exe file with pictures

Tags: python, pyinstaller

im triyng to convert game that i wrote in python with pictures to exe file . if i convert file without pics , its work, but with pictures it does not,I used pyinstaller. Is there any other process with pictures

Answer (score 0):

The **main** problem is that, your `.exe` file does **not** see your images!

First of all, **make sure** you're using relative paths to your images.

If you did, you should put the images beside your executable file as the same level as your main.py file, for example, if you have a project structure like this :

```sh
.
├── assets
│   ├── fonts-folder
│   │   ├── OFL.txt
│   │   └── Rubik-Regular.ttf
│   ├── imag1.jpg
│   └── icon.png
└── src
    └── main.py
```

After generating `file.exe` you **should** put your `file.exe` into an executable directory, so your project structure will be looked like that :

```sh
.
├── executable
│   └── file.exe
├── assets
│   ├── fonts-folder
│   │   ├── OFL.txt
│   │   └── Rubik-Regular.ttf
│   ├── imag1.jpg
│   └── icon.png
└── src
    └── main.py
```

**OR (NOT RECOMMENDED)**

you can just put your `.exe` file beside your main.py file, so your project structure may look like this:

```sh
.
├── assets
│   ├── fonts-folder
│   │   ├── OFL.txt
│   │   └── Rubik-Regular.ttf
│   ├── imag1.jpg
│   └── icon.png
└── src
    ├── main.py
    └── file.exe
```

Comment: I might also add that you can somewhat include the images in your spec file(if you do it manually like me).